# Pandas boolean value pivot on multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I got a problem on pivoting my table based on value column.

Suppose we have a multiindex dataframe `grade`:

with indexes are `Country`, `Date`, `Group` and column `Status`

```
                        Status
Country Date    Group   
US  2019-12-31  Group A Absent
                Group B Not Pass
                Group C Absent
    2020-01-02  Group A Pass
                Group B Pass
                Group C Pass
...     ...     ...     ...
ID  2020-04-14  Group A Pass
                Group B Pass
                Group C Pass
    2020-04-15  Group A Pass
                Group B Pass
                Group C Pass
```

I want to unstack the column `group` and `Status` and make a checklist based on `Status` columns.

So in the end, we got a new dataframe `checklist_grade` with columns `Absent`, `Not Pass`, `Pass` for each `group` and value `v` in the corresponding `status` value columns.

For ease of understanding the illustration we wanted:

```
                    Status                              
                    Group A                     Group B                     Group C     
Country Date        Absent  Not Pass    Pass    Absent  Not Pass    Pass    Absent  Not Pass    Pass
US      2019-12-31  v                                               v                           v       
        2020-01-02                      v                           v                           v
...     ...         ...     ...         ...     ...     ...         ...     ...     ...         ...
ID      2020-04-14              v                                   v                           v
        2020-04-15              v                                   v                           v
```

I'm trying to unstack the `grade` dataframe but it only breakdown until `group`:

```
                    Status
                    Group A     Group B     Group C
Country Date            
US      2019-12-31  Absent      Not Pass    Absent
        2020-01-02  Pass        Pass        Pass
...     ...         ...         ...         ...
ID      2020-04-14  Pass        Pass        Pass
        2020-04-15  Pass        Pass        Pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new column, convert `Status` to `MultiIndex` and reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.assign(New='v')
       .set_index('Status', append=True)
       .unstack([2,3])
       .rename(columns={'New':'Status'}))
print (df)
                    Status                                         
Group              Group A  Group B Group C Group A Group B Group C
Status              Absent Not Pass  Absent    Pass    Pass    Pass
Country Date                                                       
ID      2020-04-14     NaN      NaN     NaN       v       v       v
        2020-04-15     NaN      NaN     NaN       v       v       v
US      2019-12-31       v        v       v     NaN     NaN     NaN
        2020-01-02     NaN      NaN     NaN       v       v       v
```

Last if necessary all combinations levels in `MultiIndex` add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.columns.levels), axis=1)
print (df)
                    Status                                              \
                   Group A               Group B               Group C   
                    Absent Not Pass Pass  Absent Not Pass Pass  Absent   
Country Date                                                             
ID      2020-04-14     NaN      NaN    v     NaN      NaN    v     NaN   
        2020-04-15     NaN      NaN    v     NaN      NaN    v     NaN   
US      2019-12-31       v      NaN  NaN     NaN        v  NaN       v   
        2020-01-02     NaN      NaN    v     NaN      NaN    v     NaN   



                   Not Pass Pass  
Country Date                      
ID      2020-04-14      NaN    v  
        2020-04-15      NaN    v  
US      2019-12-31      NaN  NaN  
        2020-01-02      NaN    v
```

Comment: Need to `df.sort_index(axis=1)` to make sure the columns breakdown neatly. Thanks